# Find fixed length of integers from random length of string

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to app script.

I have a range of cells with random length of text and numbers (cells a1:a20)

In each cell, there is a six digit number but at random position in each cell.
Example: 
A1 = abcd 123456
A2 = mnndhfjf 234567

I would like to get this six digit number in the next cell (b1:b20)
B1 = 123456
B2 = 234567

How can i do this in app script?

Thank you.

Comment: Try something and show us what you tried.

Comment: Regex will be your friend ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is it always 6 digits? And is it also always on the right end of the cell?

If so something like this:

```
var str = "abcd 123456";
var res = str.slice(-6); //gets the last six digits in original order
```

Then just apply it to your situation in a loop to get the value to Column B.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in script

```
function extractNumber(str)
{
  var result = /\d+/.exec(str);
  return result;
}
```

Now in `B1`, put the formula

```
=extractNumber(A1)
```

Copy the formula to other cells too.